# List all terms of an aggregation in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am running the following ES query

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/imoveis/_search?pretty' -d 
  '{"query":{"terms":{"field1":["searchterm"]}}, 
    "aggregations":{"significantQTypes":{"significant_terms":{"field":"field1"}}}, 
    "size":0}'
```

and, instead of listing only the top 10 buckets, I would like to list 100 buckets or all of them. Still I am not sure how this is possible, any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the "size" parameter inside aggregation list as well. Please find the query below if its useful.

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "field1": [
        "searchterm"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "significantQTypes": {
      "significant_terms": {
        "field": "field1",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```